# Azure Batch failure while loading large data

Tags: r, azure, azure-batch

I am loading ~2 GB of data to perform some tasks in Azure Batch over 10 machines.
Regardless of what type of machine I am allocating, the task always fails. (it doesn't fail when i reduce the size to less than 500 MB).
there is no error reported in `logs` folder however I get below errors in `stderr` folder,
Is this something related to runtime error with regard to readRDS? is there any parameter to increase it?
thanks,

```
'/usr/local/lib/R/bin/R --no-echo --no-restore --no-save --no-environ --no-restore --no-site-file --file=/mnt/batch/tasks/workitems/job20210430184501/job-1/jobpreparation/wd/worker.R --args 1 1 0 pass'

Error in readRDS(paste0(batchJobPreparationDirectory, "/", batchJobEnvironment)) : 
  error reading from connection
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with Azure Batch, but with your program/library you are using or how you are using said program/library. Your task execution will not start if files specified as part of resource files do not download properly (i.e., you will not see `stdout.txt` or `stderr.txt` since the process associated with the task will not get created).

Comment: I am using R with docker image. I don't think the problem is with the program/library that I am using as the process finishes fine if I downsize data to 1/4. my guess is since I am using `doAzureParallel`, azure batch receives all data then read it using readRDS before allocating it to any machine and the problem could be timeout on readRDS on azure batch side. in addition ,`logs` and  `stdout.text` are empty (probably showing task failed before it got created). `stderr.txt` is not empty as i mentioned but  `stderr.txt` also reports errors before task get created if i am not mistaken.

Comment: Correct, if you see the stdout.txt/stderr.txt files, then the process was at least created. After the process is created and started, then Azure Batch does not interfere with its execution unless a task constraint has been placed on it (such as  maxWallclockTime). I'd suggest examining your program again for issues, additionally, ensure the VM size you picked is capable of handling the demands of your program/input data.